# Does GPLv2 allow removing link to original work and adding limitations?

Tags: gpl-2

I am a new software developer, so I tend to have works with many open source project on the Internet.

I have a few question about the GPL licence, can someone help me to understand them, and if possible, point to where the rule said so in the GPL licence?

1) If the program (webbased) using Python display some image/logo and link referring to the original work, and I change that image and remove that link, do I break any of the GPL rule? I will selling this product, and the user will also received the source code.

2) If I make some limitation to the software by either changing the code/create an external code or create a licence, do I break any GPL license?

Comment: Could you clarify 2. "by either changing the code/create an external code" part seems to make sense (GPL is all about allowing you to extend the code, after all), but when you say "or create a license" I do not understand what you mean. The license is GPL.

Comment: @brandin after some reading, I think what I want to ask for that part is, If I extend the open source code to make it check for an external file(something like what Microsoft word do) and if licence file are not there, the code will not work.

Comment: Will you also give customers the source code of the "license file checking" mechanism, i.e. are they allowed to hire someone to remove that check if they don't like that feature?

Comment: Yes, they can remove that feature if they can find it. That will be OK right?

Comment: But we will make it if they made any change and the system crash, we won't be responsible for it

Comment: Understandably you only want to support YOUR version, not some unknown modifications if your business case is selling your customized version and support of it.  Several technical ways to do that, such as simply checking hashes of all binaries, etc. against a known list of your distributed builds. Or perhaps providing the software as as cloud service instead of letting the client self host - under gplv2 at that point, you may not even need to distribute source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) if the program (webbased)using python display some image/logo and link referring to the original work, and I change that image and remove that link, do I break any of the GPL rule? I will selling this product, and the user will also received the source code.

No. The GPL allows you to change all parts of the code. Th only things you are not allowed to change are the copyright statements and the information which license applies.
The requirement to keep existing copyright notices and license information is stated in clause 1:

> > [...] provided that you conspicuously and appropriately publish on each copy an appropriate copyright notice and disclaimer of warranty; keep intact all the notices that refer to this License and to the absence of any warranty;

.

> 2) If I make some limitation to the software by either changing the code/create an external code or create a licence, do I break any GPL license

You are allowed to add a end-user license check (verification that a license file or a dongle is present and contains the correct information) to your code, but the GPL license also requires that you publish *all* source code and give modification and distribution rights. This means that any recipient of your application can remove the license check and re-distribute that version.
That makes the business model that relies on such a license check immediately non-viable as your first customer can also become a competitor providing a cheaper product with the same functionality and fewer restrictions.